# Regex pattern with subpattern exceptions (Python)

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I am using BeautifulSoup to extract tabledata tags from a table. The TD's have a class of either 'a','u','e','available-unavailable' or 'unavailable-available'. (Yes, I know quirky class names but hey...)

Here's an example:

```
<tr>
  <td class="u">4</td>
  <td class="unavailable-available">5</td>
  <td class="a'>6</td>
  <td class="available-unavailable">7</td>
  <td class="u">8</td>
  ...
```

I've been working with a line which incorporates an re.compile():

```
  tab = [int(tag.string) for tag in soup.find('table',{'summary':tableSummary}).findAll("td", attrs = {"class": re.compile('\Aa')})]
```

I need to extract all the td's with a class name of 'a' and 'unavailable-available'. I have been trying some negative-lookahead assertions but without much luck. I would value any regex legends who can produce the correct regex...

Comment: Do you really have html with mismatched quotes as the `"a'` entry shows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table.findAll('td', attrs = {"class":re.compile(r'(^|\s)(a|unavailable-available)($|\s)')})
```

This matches start of string or whitespace followed by "a" or "unavailable-available" followed by whitespace or end of string. So it'll match all these sorts of things

```
class="a"
class="a ui-xxx"
class="ui-xxx a"
class="ui-xxx a ui-yyy"
class="unavailable-available"
class="unavailable-available foo"
```

Comment: +1 for robustness and being explicit about what is being searched for.

Comment: You have to use a raw string or the `\s` will be misinterpreted. I took the liberty of editing your post.

Comment: @Tim: normally I'd remember but this time I forgot. Thanks for updating it; it's more precise that way - though it's not more accurate (`'\s' == '\\s' == r'\s'`, try it). I would have noticed if it hadn't worked, 'cos I did try it.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. Since `\s` has no special meaning in a string, the backslash will be treated as a literal. This won't happen with `\b` though, for example (`'\b' == '\\b'` returns `False`).

Answer (score 0):

HA!

```
re.compile('^a(?!vail)|^un')
```

- matches all starting a's not proceeded by 'vail' and all starting 'un's. Good un!

Answer (score 0):

I bow to the RE prowess of others. But as an alternative datapoint to BS+RE, here is a pyparsing rendition (assuming those nasty mismatched quotes get fixed):

```
html = """
<tr> 
  <td class="u">4</td> 
  <td class="unavailable-available">5</td> 
  <td class="a">6</td> 
  <td class="available-unavailable">7</td> 
  <td class="u">8</td> 
"""

from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags, withAttribute, oneOf, SkipTo

# define opening and closing tag expressions
td,tdEnd = makeHTMLTags("TD")

# only want opening TD's with certain classes
td.setParseAction(withAttribute(**{'class':oneOf("a unavailable-available")}))

# define overall pattern
patt = td + SkipTo(tdEnd)("contents") + tdEnd

# search for matches
for t in patt.searchString(html):
    print t.dump()
```

Prints:

```
['TD', ['class', 'unavailable-available'], False, '5', '</TD>']
- class: unavailable-available
- contents: 5
- empty: False
- endTd: </TD>
- startTd: ['TD', ['class', 'unavailable-available'], False]
  - class: unavailable-available
  - empty: False
['TD', ['class', 'a'], False, '6', '</TD>']
- class: a
- contents: 6
- empty: False
- endTd: </TD>
- startTd: ['TD', ['class', 'a'], False]
  - class: a
  - empty: False
```

For each match, you can also access `t.contents` and `t['class']` (have to use dict syntax because `class` is a Python keyword) directly.